# What is different between Aspect and Associations in context of Content Model?

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, content-model

I am very new to Alfresco and trying to understand the Content Model from [here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html#introduction). I am trying to find the answer of following question, but not getting.

What is different between **Aspect** and **Associations** in context of Content Model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite easy actually:

- **An aspect** is simply a collection of properties that can ***optionally*** get added to a content of a specific type. (ie: an aspect called webable for content that can be published to the web, with one single property indicating if it is already published `true`/`false` and one other with the date of last publication)
- **An association** is a ***link*** or a ***relationship*** between two content types (ie: link a generated pdf file to the original docx file/template)